# nodemailer hotmail auth can't find details

Tags: smtp, hotmail, nodemailer

I really dislike microsofts ui it is terrible

im trying to setup my node.js app to mail using hotmail but cant.

i have got so far using:

```
var hotmail=nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{service:'Hotmail','auth':{'user':' exampl@hotmail.com','pass':'MY-Normal-User-Pass'}});
```

I get the error:

```
Message sent: 250 2.6.0  <1383551761565.976a644a@Nodemailer> Queued mail for delivery
```

[image]

so tried my normal user pass and my email now says sent but also says its queued i think 250 is like 'you don't have permission' from what i have read on google...

and check this, my hotmail sent box shows each email i have tried to send but my client does not receive them?!

also I have sent using gmail fine!

```
var gmail=nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{service:'Gmail','auth':{'user':'example@gmail.com','pass':'ufufufufufur7yryed'}});
```

it was the two step verification on goole ! very easy!!

```
if(r.email.search('@hotmail')!==-1||r.email.search('@live')!==-1||r.email.search('@outlook')!==-1){
        hotmail.sendMail({
            subject:c+' update received...',
            from:'example@hotmail.com',
            to:r.email,
            html: 'Click this <b><a href="http://example.com/'+c+'-example.php?q='+q+'">link</a></b> to veiw your update.'
            },function(error,response){
                if(error){console.log(error+'!!!!!!!!!!!!');socket.emit('email_send.err');}
                else{console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);socket.emit('email_send.ok',{'result':'200:ok'});}});
                }
    else if(r.email.search('@gmail')!==-1||r.email.search('@')!==-1){
        gmail.sendMail({
            subject:c+' update received...',
            from:'example@gmail.com',
            to:r.email,
            html: 'Click this <b><a href="http://example.com/'+c+'-example.php?q='+q+'">link</a></b> to veiw your update.'
             },function(error,response){
                if(error){console.log(error+'!!!!!!!!!!!!');socket.emit('email_send.err');}
                else{console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);socket.emit('email_send.ok',{'result':'200:ok'});}});
                }
                });
```

why is (not so)hotmail showing me sent messages when it's sent only storing my messages in my sent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Message sent: 250` means that the message was accepted. Outgoing SMTP servers do not send mail instantly but through a queue - once previous messages in the queue are sent out, your message will be as well.

If the message does not reach recipients inbox it might have got lost in the way, for example might get marked as spam etc.

Comment: but i used hotmail to email hotmail, how the hell can it be spam or lost lol!?